# One to one function

Tags: functions

I am stuck on this problem can someone solve it for me?

> Show that the function $f(x) = \dfrac{3^x}{3^x + 1}$ is one-to-one

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy to see that

$$f'(x)= \frac{3^x \ln(3)}{(3^x+1)^2}.$$

Hence $f'(x) >0$ for all $x$. The mean value theorem shows then, that $f$ is one-to- one.

Comment: could you explain how does MVT relates to one-to-one functions? as I watched yt videos and read about MVT but can't understand this yet.

Answer (score 2):

To prove that a function $f: A \to B$ is one-to-one we need to show that
$\require{cancel}$
$$ \forall x,y \in A: f(x)=f(y) \implies x=y $$

So, take $f(x)=\dfrac{3^x}{3^x + 1}$ and plug $x,y$:

$$ f(x) = f(y) \\
\dfrac{3^x}{3^x + 1} = \dfrac{3^y}{3^y + 1} \\
3^x(3^y + 1) = 3^y(3^x +1) \\
\cancel{3^{x+y}} + 3^x = \cancel{3^{x+y}} + 3^y \\
3^x = 3^y \implies x=y $$

So, $f$ is one-to-one.